# sceneform cannot load gltf (java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.io.FileNotFoundException)

Tags: android

I am from a non-English speaking country, so I am not familiar with English. Thank you for your understanding.

I couldn't convert to obj as an asset(I was using sceneform 1.17.1)
So I tried to load the object using the .gltf

However, it does not load with an error that the file cannot be found.
this is my code
(I'm using Kotlin.)

```
    ModelRenderable.builder().setSource(
        context,
        RenderableSource.builder().setSource(
            context,
            Uri.parse("assets/models/untitled_geometry.gltf"),
            RenderableSource.SourceType.GLTF2
        ).setScale(0.75f)
            .setRecenterMode(RenderableSource.RecenterMode.ROOT)
            .build()
    )
        .build()
        .thenAccept(Consumer { modelRenderable: ModelRenderable ->
            DlogUtil.d(TAG, "랜더링이 비엇나? " + modelRenderable)
            repeatingMaterial = modelRenderable.material
        })
        .exceptionally {
            DlogUtil.d(TAG, "랜더링이 비엇나?")
            return@exceptionally null
        }
    
}
```

app gradle

```
    implementation "com.google.ar:core:1.23.0"
implementation "com.google.ar.sceneform:core:1.17.1"
implementation "com.google.ar.sceneform.ux:sceneform-ux:1.17.1"
implementation 'com.google.ar.sceneform:assets:1.17.1'
```

project gradle

```
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

    classpath 'com.google.ar.sceneform:plugin:1.17.1'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

this is my file path
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkjHm.png)

Comment: You could try `Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/models/untitled_geometry.gltf"),`.

Comment: @frankenapps  Thank you for your help! lol, BUT I I ran into a new error, "java.io.FileNotFoundException: /android_asset/models/result.bin". 
Is this error telling me there is a problem with my gltf file?

Comment: @frankenapps oh.. I catch my gltf file error. THANK A LOT FOR YOUR HELP!